# How to get write permission to a /var/lib folder for app installed as a distiubutable package

Tags: linux, permissions, debian, installation

I'm creating a mono app and I've build up a *.deb installer.

In windows I write quite a bit of configuration information into the program data directory.  The linux corollary seems to be /var/lib/[appname].  I've figured out how to create the directories as part of the install package, but when the app goes to run I get an excpetion because the app doesn't have write permission.

How do I get my app to have write permission to the /var/lib/[appname] folder?  Is that the correct place to put things like a local db for an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only way to do this is via the postinst script file.

You can use that hook to execute a script to chmod the directories to anything you want. You can find the complete documentation for the postinst file here: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#maintscripts